# When will a moving vehicle stop faster: when the brakes are applied and the wheels are slipping, or just before?

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction

When will a moving vehicle stop faster: when the brakes are applied and the wheels are slipping, or just before the wheels start slipping? Explain why.

Comment: sounds very like a homework question, isn't it? :)